# How to add custom fields to WooCommerce webhook

Tags: woocommerce, webhooks, hook-woocommerce

I want to add a custom field to WooCommerce **Order Created** webhook

How to add this custom field "mp_pix_qr_code" to the WooCommerce order created webhook?

[image]

I've tried custom codes. I'm expecting a snippet to add this new field to the order created webhook

Comment: Your question is unclear and not detailed… Please edit your question to clarify it. Also, we expect from you to provide your own real code attempt in your question.